# How many users pressed the button?

Tags: ios, iphone

So, what I want to do, is to track any kind of user interaction with certain features in my app (e. g. night mod).

Comment: What are you literally trying to achieve?

Comment: You can use Firebase event tracker.

Comment: I just want to collect the data of how many of my users use the certain feature

Comment: @mqz.kim that's exactly what I was looking for. I just didn't  know, how to google it. Thanks a lot

Comment: These two pages would be helpful.
https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/android/events

Comment: https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/6317479?hl=en

Comment: @mqz.kim what I meant is I didn't know, how to call this system

Comment: Do you use Cocoapod or not?
If you use Cocoapod, you can just add 'Firebase' easily, but if not, I recommend u to read the article in above pages..

Comment: If I may, what was needed in your question is specifying "sever-side" code. And if I may, what would **very** much help anyone searching this site downstream is answering your own question once you glean it. Not trying to be critical, just trying to help everyone in the future like this site has done for me over the years.

Comment: @dfd thanks for your help, I simplified my question, many useless words were said :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to count of button click then you can increment counter in **Database** using **API** call. But if you want tracking kind of thing then you can user [Google Analicts](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v3/) or [Flurry](https://developer.yahoo.com/flurry/docs/analytics/gettingstarted/ios/) to do.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to use some kind of analytics to see which features of ur app are most used and which are not, which of buttons is pressed more etc. So i recommend :[Google Analytics](https://analytics.google.com).